# How to check if element is visible in viewport?

Tags: grails, spock, geb

If I am at the bottom of the page how can I check if some element is visible if that element is for example at the top of the page.

I need to write a test where I scroll down to the bottom of the page and when I click on div it moves me back to the top of the page. Next step is to check if I am at that position. 
My idea was that I just need to check if that element is visible but it turns out that it is not that easy to do. Any suggestions?

.isDisplayed() and .isFocused() is not what I need.

**Edit:**
I had an idea and I need two methods for it.

First one is to get y coordinate of the element (we need only y), but the problem is that getY() returns number relative to your current position, so I need something that will move me to that element and then get y coordinate. So my method looked something like this:

```
int getYCoordinat() {
        // first move to the element
        interact {
            moveToElement(element)
        }
        // get y coord
            return element.getY()
    }
```

second method looked something like this:

```
boolean isScrolledToElement(int yCoordinateOfElement) {
            int y = element.getY()
            return y == yCoordinateOfElement
        }
    }
```

So first I would call *getYCoordinat()*, store integer into *yCoordinateOfElement*.
Then I would click on div that moves me to the element and call *isScrolledToElement(yCoordinateOfElement)*.

But it doesnt work because moveToElement moves you to that element only if the element is not visible. So if we stay where we are because *moveToElement()* didn't move us, because element is already visible, we get the wrong Y coordinate that won't be same as the one which we get when we click on div that moves us to the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the only solution I could find.](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.com/2013/05/is-element-on-visible-screen.html) Basically you need to see if the pixel coordinate of the bottom-right corner of your element is within the window.

Taken from the link:

```
private boolean isWebElementVisible(WebElement w) {
    Dimension weD = w.getSize();
    Point weP = w.getLocation();
    Dimension d = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    int x = d.getWidth();
    int y = d.getHeight();
    int x2 = weD.getWidth() + weP.getX();
    int y2 = weD.getHeight() + weP.getY();

    return x2 <= x && y2 <= y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I made method that just takes the height of a parent. Then it checks if the element is in that size, if it is then its visible. It is nothing special but if I wanted to make exactly what the test case said then I would need to use something like sikuli script (http://www.sikuli.org) and check with screenshots if the link scrolled me to the linked div.